# Blank Seaborn Barplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot a barplot of a pandas df in seaborn however it always appears as white bars which don't show up on white background. Setting to style=darkgrid means I can see them but I want them to be much more prominent and for some reason colour seems to have no effect. Anyone have any ideas?

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.barplot(x="index", y="Frequency", data=explore, orient="v")
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If colour is the issue means, not able to see properly then you can also use the palette property of seaborn to choose different colour palette other than the default one.

More information about the palette -: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html